# PysimpleGUI Message Box

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

I wrote the whole code the only thing disappointing me is that I can't change the input rows and column let me show you what I mean by this.

[I want this kind of dialog box, check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tob84.png)

[Instead I get this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77NYM.png)

I can't use the `sg.output` here because it raises exception when throwing something special like ** in it

**Is there any way to change the length of `sg,Input` or any alternative you better get an idea by seeing images.**

Comment: IMO, you may use wrong element `sg.Input` for it, should be `sg.Multiline`. The height of `sg.Input` is always 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a MutiLine input like this sample code

```
[sg.Multiline('Many\nLines\n Here',size=(28,28),key='-MANY_LINES-'),],
```

Full code like so

```
 txt2=""
#Initialize a holder variable 
fruits=['apple', 'orange', 'pears', 'tomatoes']

#Convert from List to Text with New line
for i in fruits:txt2=f"{fruits}{i}\n"

#Create layout
layout2 = [[sg.Multiline(txt2,size=(28,28),key='-Items-'),],[sg.Ok()] ]

#Single shot Popup Window
sg.Window('Scroll to see the whole list of fruits', layout2,finalize=True).read(close=True)
```

[image: Example of PySimpleGUI Popup with Many lines of output and Scrolling of text.]

Comment: How to remove scroll bar

Comment: use sg.Input instead of sg.Multiline

Comment: It only show one line height